# How to select date between two date after 2 month using sql

Tags: sql

Start date-`01/01/2018`, end date:`01/10/2018`. difference: 2 month,

Output:

```
01/01/2018
01/03/2018
01/05/2018
01/07/2018
```

Comment: Are you using `SQL-SERVER` or `MySQL` ? Please mention. Just `sql` is vague.

Comment: There are different SQL languages. you should mention your database name and even version or the SQL name like PSQL, TSQL, SQLScript and so on.

Comment: Sql server...2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
With dt As
 (
 Select @Startdate As [TheDate]
 Union All
 Select DateAdd(month, 2, TheDate) From dt Where [TheDate] < @enddate
 ) 
select [TheDate] from dt
```

Comment: Assuming, this is a SQL-Server solution you will probably need to specify the variable names `start date` and `end date` as `@startdate` and `@enddate`.

Comment: Thanks Brother... It Works.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can try below

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  [Start Date Time] DATETIME,
  [End Date Time] DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'2018-01-01 13:00:00.000','2018-10-01 10:00:00.000');


;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID,[Start Date Time] startTime,[End Date Time] endTime
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,CAST(CAST(DATEADD(month,2,startTime)AS DATE) AS DATETIME),endTime 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CAST(CAST(DATEADD(month,2,startTime) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) < endTime
)
SELECT id,
       startTime AS 'Start Date Time',endTime

FROM CTE
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f48ed/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query-:

```
declare @startDate date,@EndDate date;
set @startDate='2018-01-01';
set @EndDate='2018-10-01';
while DATEADD(month,2,@startDate)<@EndDate
begin
print @startDate
set @startDate=DATEADD(month,2,@startDate)
end
```